# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: out of memory when storing 80MB blob

Tags: postgresql, memory, lob, bytea

I'm trying to insert an 80MB file into a bytea column and getting:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: out of memory
Detail: Failed on request of size 87078404.
```

The column is mapped as byte[].

```
@Column(name = "document_data")
protected byte[] data;
```

I'm wondering what is causing it an what should be the long term solution. Switch to lob/oid maybe?

Comment: Please show us the code that runs the `insert` statement. Are you using a `PreparedStatement`? If yes how are you passing the actual blob data? When using `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream()` I have no problem saving a 300MB file with a JVM that was started using `-Xmx128m`.

Comment: I'm using a dropwizard application which in turn uses hibernate. I'm suspecting I'm running out of memory on the box. I'm monitoring as we speak and memory is very low:

Comment: Based on the exception, the OOM error occurs on the _client_, not on the server. Please show us the code that does the actual insert.